# rshiny module not printing input to output

Tags: user-interface, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Simple `reprex` here, but I am trying to print the input as a small test to see if my app is working:

```
test_ui <- function(id) {
    fluidPage(
        selectInput("sel_id", "label", 1:10),
        textOutput(NS(id, "sel_text"))
    )
}

test_server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            output$sel_text <- renderText({input$sel_id})
        }
    )
}

demo <- function() {
    ui <- fluidPage(
        test_ui("x")
    )
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        test_server("x")
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
}

demo()
```

I was expecting the text to print below the input box but all I got was the select box:
[image]

I tried substituting the output line with:

```
output$sel_text <- renderText({"test_text"})
```

and it printed:
[image]

So it must be something to do with the input values. Weirdly enough in my main (more complex) app, writing the code directly into the ui/server files works, so I must be tripping up on some aspect of modules I don't understand. Would greatly appreciate if someone could point out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me! All I forgot was the following call to `NS()`:

```
selectInput(NS(id, "sel_id"), "label", 1:10)
```